# Heroku completely messed up my Laravel login (Laravel 9)

Tags: laravel, authentication, heroku, laravel-9

I am currently trying to host my Laravel 9 project on Heroku. Everything works more or less fine, until it comes to the Login. The first thing which is horrible is the fact that the login style is completely messed up, my login has been fully made with the laravel default login implementation and in local everything works as it should.
[My current laravel-9 login page on Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcSNq.png)

This is currently my login page...

In addition to all of that, whenever I try to login, I get the 419 page error. And yes, I did setup properly the postgre database and added all the migrations.

I tried everything I possibly could. I looked everywhere online, but no one is able to help me out....

Comment: Don't blame Heroku: it didn't change your code. Your application is failing to run properly on Heroku. What errors do you see in your browser console? Are you serving static files correctly? What do [your server-side logs say](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs)?

Comment: Include bootstap css in master blade and bootstrap js and will work fine.

Comment: @Eng_Farghly Thank you for your answer, how can I add the bootstrap css and bootstrap js in my master blade? And what do you mean by master blade, the welcome  blade (homepage)? Or the authenticator blade?

Comment: master blade file that is located in resources/layouts/app.blade.php

Comment: @Chris, then how come everything works completely fine whenever I am in local? Might not be Heroku but I am not sure its mine either.

Comment: @LucaGirotti, I'm just saying you should take responsibility for building and configuring your application correctly. We have no idea how you're running your application locally, but Heroku doesn't change your code. Again, _what do your logs say?_

Comment: An image of your login page tells us nothing. We don't know how it's supposed to look, we don't know what code you're using, etc. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris What can I share you? I can't really share the whole Laravel rep. And to be completely honest, I don't really know what I could share you, since the whole login process has been totally made by Laravel itself.

Comment: @LucaGirotti, for the third time, your logs would be a great start. And you should really only be asking one question at a time, so either ask about the page rendering, or ask about why login isn't working. Those are separate issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go to resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php and include bootstrap.css in header of the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"  />
```

And include bootstrap.js in scripts section:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find the script section? in the app.blade.php?

Comment: Before closing body tag in app. blade. php add bootstrap.js script

Comment: didnt work... I have also tried to include the bootstrap js in the header tag and nothing changed. What I did at the begining was including the bootstrap CSS in the header and the bootstrap script in the body, and that also didn't work...

Comment: Watch this video https://youtu.be/rBNPzBYDl4Q?list=PLRheCL1cXHrsok0K0qz2b612zoCSe4VPW&t=111  it will fix your problem.

Comment: Not really to be honest. Somehow my styles and scripts are used through "livewire" and I do not have any of the files which are present in the video. In addition to all of that, the login works perfeclty fine whenever I am in local, heroku just completely messes everything up....

Comment: Can you share you project via github link, I hope help you to fix you problem.

Comment: I dont think I will be able to share my project, since its a group project...

Comment: And really I really want to specify the fact that on my current localhost everything works perfectly, I really don't know why heroku is creating this big mess, I am really disappointed...